# Given matrix A with $A_{i,j} = f(i,j)$, how can I find out if A is positive semidefinite?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, determinant, positive-definite

I'm working on a problem whose solution relies on finding if an arbitrary matrix A is positive semi-definite. A is real valued, square and symmetric, and each of its entries are given by:

$A_{ii} = f(i)$

$A_{ij} = A_{ji} = f(i,j)$

The problem is that this is part of an induction proof, where the size N of the matrix represents the problem at step N. Are there any simple ways of finding out if A is positive semi-definite? Finding the characteristic equation is pretty hard, given that it would rely on finding the determinant of an arbitrarily large matrix A(NxN).

Thank you.

EDIT: I'm looking for a method that is non dependent on f(), since my f() is quite extensive. Some analogous to finding the characteristic equation using the simple:

$det(A-\alpha I) = (f(1) - \alpha)(f(2)-\alpha) - f(1,2)^2$

for N=2

Comment: What is the function f?

Comment: I was looking for a method that would be independent of f(), since f() is quite extensive. it involves the i-th element of another vector, for instance.

Comment: if N =2, for instance, I could just take the trace and determinant of the matrix: det(A) = f(1)f(2) - f(1,2)^2 and tr(A) = f(1) + f(2) and check if both are non-negative. But formulas like this are not transferable to N > > 2 I guess

Comment: Related topic: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_kernel

Comment: "A Hermitian matrix M is positive-semidefinite if and only if all principal minors of M are nonnegative": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion . Although this still requires computing many determinants.

Comment: @William There's not going to be a good method that works for all such functions. If you're specifically talking about positive definite kernels, then you might find [the rules listed here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/150964/128205) to be helpful